# PHP: How to stop executing code when refreshed?

Tags: php, html, redirect

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to build a simple login-form with HTML, PHP and Bootstrap. I have a login page and a registration page. I wanted to display a success message once a user was created. But it keeps showing when I come back from a different page and also when I refresh the page.

With  header("Location:registration.php"); I redirect to the same page. This prevents inserting into the database when I refresh the page. See my code below from "registration.php".

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['add_user'])) {
//When submitted store entered data in a variable
$add_username = $_POST['add_username'];
$add_password = $_POST['add_password'];

//Database query
$query = "INSERT INTO users(username, user_password) VALUES('{$add_username}', '{$add_password}')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if(!$result) {
        die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
    } else {
        $_SESSION['success_message'] = " ";
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
         $_SESSION['success_message'] = "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'><strong>User Created</strong><br><a href='index.php'>Log In</a></div>";
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Send a parameter to the link too, something like, `registration.php?reg=1` in order to differentiate.

Comment: Have you run [session_start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before any php output?

Comment: You're showing too few lines for diagnosis.

Comment: @KoalaYeung Is this better?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: You need to unset your session message after displaying it.

Comment: @Qirel I tried. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to avoid issue.

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        // ... your code here

        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
```

Comment: You have to uset your session value after showing once. 

if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
  echo $_SESSION['message'];
  unset($_SESSION['message']);
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (empty($_SESSION['success_message'])) {
  // set and display message
}
```

This way you will display the message only the first time.

Comment: Can YOU be a bit more specific? What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is   $_SESSION['success_message'] keeps showing when you refresh the page or navigate from a different page to registration.php